# State already shows as updated to new value in componentWillReceiveProps. Is there a way to check for props change now?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function when a component receives new props from it's parent.

I am checking it in `componentWillReceiveProps` like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('props urls length :',  nextProps.urls.length);
    console.log('state urls length :',  this.state.urls.length);

    if(nextProps.urls.length!= this.state.urls.length){
        console.log('new props in canvas in IF :',nextProps.urls);
        let urls = this.props.urls;
        let urlsOrder = [];
        urls.map((item)=>{
            let newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/tripdoc/split/','');
            if(nextProps.type === 'maildoc'||nextProps.type==='itinerary'||nextProps.item && nextProps.item.doctype === 'important' && nextProps.doctypes && nextProps.item.doctypes === 'emaildoc'){
                newItem = item.replace(' http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/maildoc/split','');
            }else if(nextProps.type === 'agency'){
                newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/defaultdocs/7/split','');
            }else if(nextProps.type === 'clients'){
                newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/clientsdoc/split','');
            }
            urlsOrder.push(newItem);
        });
        this.setState({
            urlsOrder,
            urls:nextProps.urls
        });

        this.pdfConversion(nextProps.urls);
        setTimeout(nextProps.hideLoading(),2000);
    }
}
```

the problem is that in these console logs I can clearly see that the values are the same

```
console.log('props urls length :',  nextProps.urls.length);
console.log('state urls length :',  this.state.urls.length);
```

therefore the check I have put is not working and it's not going inside the `if` statement.

I have tried using `derivedStateFromProps` and that is showing a similar thing also.

the values are same so the check is not working there also.
I mean obviously the props will change since the parent component is sending newly updated data, but how come the state is changing automatically in this child component?

please tell me where am I going wrong??

And let's say this is how it should behave then please tell me how do I call a certain function when the props or the state does change?

Here's how I tried it in componentDidUpdate

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        console.log('prevProps',prevProps);
        console.log('prevstate : ',prevState.urls.length);
        console.log('new props in canvas :',this.props.urls.length);
        if(prevState.urls.length!= this.props.urls.length){
            console.log('new props in canvas in IF :',this.props.urls);
            let urls = this.props.urls;
            let urlsOrder = [];
            urls.map((item)=>{
                let newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/tripdoc/split/','');
                if(this.props.type === 'maildoc'||this.props.type==='itinerary'||this.props.item && this.props.item.doctype === 'important' && this.props.item.doctypes && this.props.item.doctypes === 'emaildoc'){
                    newItem = item.replace(' http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/maildoc/split','');
                }else if(this.props.type === 'agency'){
                    newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/defaultdocs/7/split','');
                }else if(this.props.type === 'clients'){
                    newItem = item.replace('http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/clientsdoc/split','');
                }
                urlsOrder.push(newItem);
            });
            this.setState({
                urlsOrder,
                urls:this.props.urls
            });

            this.pdfConversion(this.props.urls);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to call a function when a component receives new props from it's parent.

This organically results in a render (update). Try using [`componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.
>   This method is not called for the initial render.

You have a clear opportunity to compare `this.props` and `prevProps` in this lifecycle hook, as well as `this.state` and `prevState`.

It's also worth mentioning that [`componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) with future releases

Comment: nope. already tried that. didnt work. have put the code for it in original post too

Comment: Well, that's now a matter of your logic _within_ the hook. The life-cycle hook was wrong, now you have the opportunity to unblock yourself. You literally ask "to call a function when a component receives new props from it's parent." This is a way to do so. I can only now conclude your logic within that is wrong, and not within scope of the question. I'd suggest asking a new question as this is likely where feedback on this one ends

Comment: really?? are we going to talk about wording of my question now?
anyways. how should I word it then? please tell me.
I think you already get what I am trying to do, so please tell me the wording or maybe go ahead and edit the wording, if this site allows that.

Comment: I'm not dissecting the wording, I'm trying to tell you that your primary question has been answered and you're now [vampiring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/1464112) the situation because clearly the logic within your hook isn't working. If that's your real concern, address that. Also, unsure how receptive you expect responses such as "nope" to be.